# selecting 'student_id' where 'pass' value is not 0 in every case

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset. I want to select all rows where the value of the 'pass' is not all zero for a student_id

```
student_id      Subject      pass

234554          Maths        1
346535          Science      0  
862789          History      0
234554          English1     1
346535          History      0
862789          Sciencre     1
```

As for student_id 346535, there is not a single pass value as 1, therefore, we ignored it

Expected Output:

```
student_id      Subject      pass

234554          Maths        1
862789          History      0
234554          English1     1
862789          Sciencre     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set_index` + `any`

```
u = df.set_index('student_id')

u.loc[u.groupby(level=0)['pass'].any()]
```

```
             Subject  pass
student_id
234554         Maths     1
862789       History     0
234554      English1     1
862789      Sciencre     1
```

---

`any` works out of the box here with `any` because it is "falsey". If you are looking for a *specific* value, and not a "falsey" value, you can mask before you `groupby` to create the indexer for `loc`

```
u['pass'].ne(val).groupby(level=0).any()
```

Comment: I want 'student_id' as a coloumn

Comment: Then just `reset_index()` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

you can `set_index` then create a mask by using `cumsum` and `groupby`

```
df.set_index('student_id',inplace=True) # set your index # 

mask = (df.loc[df.groupby(['student_id'])
             ['pass'].transform('cumsum') >= 1].index) # create your mask

df_new = df.loc[df.index.isin(mask)] # slice your df.

print(df_new.reset_index()) # print.


    student_id  Subject pass
0   234554  Maths   1
1   862789  History 0
2   234554  English1    1
3   862789  Sciencre    1
```